# How can i convert elements of an array in javascript into an independent array using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert elements of an array to independent arrays and then adding these arrays to a new array. this is what i have tried. But cannot get it to work. 
`splice` method is not working properly with `forEach`,`forEach` just runs for half array and then exits.

what i expect is something like this [['Apple'],['Banana'],['Mango'],['Pomegranate']]

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Pomegranate']

function removeArrayItem(item,index){
    return fruits.splice(0,1)
}

const fruitsList = []

fruitsList.unshift(fruits.forEach(removeArrayItem))

console.log(fruitsList)
```

Comment: post the desired output as well

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're attempting but it's probably true that `.map()` makes a lot more sense than `.forEach()`.

Comment: Anthony's answer with map seems to work with this.

Comment: You would use map for this, Anthony's answer with map works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Pomegranate']

console.log(fruits.map(fruit => [fruit]));
```

If you are set on `forEach` though, you can do it like:

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Pomegranate'];
const result = [];

fruits.forEach(fruit => result.push([fruit]));

console.log(result);
```

Something like this would work for splice:

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Pomegranate'];
const initialLength = fruits.length;
const result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < initialLength; i++) {
    result.push(fruits.splice(0,1));
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: not with `forEach`; you are mutating the array as you are iterating over it which is not good practice

Answer (score 0):

---

To convert

> ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Pomegranate']

to

> [ ["Apple"], ["Banana"], ["Mango"], ["Pomegranate"] ]

you can try

```
    //using for each 
    const usingForEach = []; 
    fruits.forEach(el => usingForEach.push([el]));

    //using map
    const usingMap = fruits.map(el => [el]);
```